# Why do I get error when replacing datagridview values in vb?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview which holds an imported excel file. I also have a MySQL database which holds the values i want to replace in my datagridview and the values that will replace the previous values.

This is my database:

[image: Database]

What I want to accomplish is to loop inside the datagridview cells and find the values inside the Content field and replace it with the corresponding value in the Convert field. For example all 1 will be replaced by 11, all Name 1 will be replaced by Std Name 1, all 18 will be replaced by 18 Years Old.

I use the following code:

```
MysqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM contents"
    MysqlComm = New MySqlCommand(MysqlQuery, MysqlConn)
    MysqlReader = MysqlComm.ExecuteReader

    While MysqlReader.Read
        Dim content = MysqlReader.GetString("Content")
        Dim convert = MysqlReader.GetString("Convert")
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvFile.Rows
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                If cell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    If cell.Value.ToString = content.ToString Then
                        cell.Value = convert.ToString
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End While

        MessageBox.Show("File successfully converted")
```

This code converts 1 = 11 and Name 1 = Std Name 1 but not 18 = 18 Years old and it shows this error.

[image: Output]

**QUESTION**
Why do I get this error and how can I fix this? Answers and suggestions are well appreciated. Thanks. :)

**UPDATE**
For those who can't see the error message, here it is.

```
The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:

System.Exception: 18 Years Old is not a valid value for Double, --->
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
 at System.Number.PraseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options,
NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
 at System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatPRovider     provider)
 at System.ComponentModel.DoubleConverter.FromString(String value,   NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)
 at     System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext  context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at    System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
 at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(Object value)
 at  System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.PushValue(Int32  boundColumnIndex, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Object value)

To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event
```

Comment: cant see error msg here....please post that too..

Comment: @akhilkumar updated my question. I included your request.

Comment: ya now understood the problem..check the datatype of the column which you are converting to "18 years old".it should be of DOUBLE.you cant input a string into column with double datatype.change the datatype of that column to string.

Comment: I been thinking about that for hours and tried to find where will I need to change the datatype. All my fields in the DB are Text except the Id (which is not used in the scenario). But because of your comment I realized that my excel column might not have the right format. I changed all the columns to Text format in excel and it worked perfectly. This was sorted. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that's the line causing you the error:

`cell.Value = convert.ToString`

It is probably because the column type is <> `String` (probably integer or double).

You can either put the value in its right type, instead of doing `ToString` when you set the value.

Another option is to make the all column types of the grid `String`. But than you'd have to take in account that the sort of the column would have to be changed (you will need to find the sort event and convert the value to the right type when you sort).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The columns of the excel file are not all text so I wasn't able to input values which are not the same type. This was sorted. :)

Comment: @Nek - Just a curious question - why do you use vb.net and not C# ?

Comment: I'm not good at C#. I'm more familiar with vb.net. But i'm taking into consideration using C# for my next projects. I need to finish this one quickly so I don't have time to study C# right now. :)

Comment: I myself know both languages, but for historic reasons of our developments, I use vb.net... thanks :)